# Postgresql- select parent table rows that satisfies condition in child table with the given array

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

Parent table has  id & user_name. 
child table has id, user_id, type_of_detail, detail_data, created_time.
the details are updated by inserting new row in child table **no update query** allowed. Data is queried by referring created_time, latest data is a valid one.

In stored procedure i am receiving multiple type_of_detail and its data as composite array 
so how can i select the parent rows that satisfies the condition in child table with the received array

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: Add sample data and expected output.

Comment: Don't forget to add a question as well.

Comment: i have added the sample data and output

Comment: number of data receiving in array is not fixed one

Comment: I assume that `user_id` is a foreign key to the parent table. What I don't understand is why `(3,C)` is not an expected result. The row with `id = 7` in the child table would suggest it.

Comment: because it is not satisfying both conditions. in id 6 it has the value of DE

Comment: both condition must be satisfied